# How to handle null values with lodash get

Tags: javascript, lodash

This is simple json

```
  {
    home: 68
    id: 1
    name: "RL Conference Room"
    nickname: null
    setpoint: 32.34
    sleep: 58
  }
```

When I get empty key this lodash function works

```
_.get(room, 'keyName', 'whenKeyNotFound')
```

But as you can see above i am getting null value in `nickname` So I want to replace it with `name` but this doesn't work.

```
_.get(room, 'nickname', 'name')
```

Is there any function in lodash which does the trick?

**Thank you!!!**

Comment: the first case works because key doesn't exists but in second case the key does exists and have a valid value

Comment: This also works but without lodash, `room?.nickname ?? name` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 10):

In one level scenario and since (in your case) `null` is also an **undesired** result it seems you are better of without lodash and simply do this:

```
room.nickname || room.name
```

It would actually be shorter and achieve the same result in your case.

You could also do:

```
let name = _.defaultTo(room.nickname, room.name)
```

[**_.defaultTo**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#defaultTo) to protects you from `null, NaN and undefined`

So in the case above you would get the `obj.name` but if you have `nickname` set you would get that.

In scenarios where you have a long path you can utilize `_.isEmpty` in a custom function like this:

```
const getOr = (obj, path, def) => {
    var val = _.get(obj, path)
    return _.isEmpty(val) ? def : val
}
```

This will handle your `null` as well as other scenarios as per [**_.isEmpty** docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEmpty).

You can simply then use as:

```
getOr(room, 'nickname', room.name)
```

And you can nest it:

```
getOr(room, 'nickname', getOr(room, 'name', 'N/A'))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can rely on the fact that [`null`, `undefined`, etc. are falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), and use the `||` operator.

```
_.get(room, 'nickname') || _.get(room, 'name')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `null` is falsy, you can do

`_.get(room, 'nickname') || 'name'`

`.get` only returns the third argument if the result is `undefined`

see: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get

Answer (score 0):

### use a custom get function

Create a utility function that works on top of the lodash get function to handle `null` values.

How `customGet()` works?

Returns the default value if the value turns out to be `null` or `undefined`

> Note: `null` values are defaulted only if the default value is provided.

```
import lodashGet from "lodash/get";

type TGetParams = Parameters<typeof lodashGet>;

export function customGet(
  object: TGetParams[0],
  path: TGetParams[1],
  defaultValue?: TGetParams[2]
) {
  const value = lodashGet(object, path);

  if (defaultValue !== undefined) {
    return value ?? defaultValue;
  }

  return value;
}
```

---

[Open in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sof-a-76194575-r8io7x?file=/src/Main.js)